# Web API ASP.NET Core Post Request 415 Unsupported Media Type for images(png, jpg)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume a POST service to be able to send images, but when I run it through Postman, I get this error.

I am making the call of that service through another api to be able to test it by Postman, it happens that when I do it and paste the image I get that 415 error. What could be happening?

{StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: { X-AREQUESTID: 1196x14887183x1 X-ANODEID: node2 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' X-ASEN: SEN-17699581 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4548966F3B9BAFC283932093C14B6CF7; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BYCQ-GVBW-0E9H-MNTX_18760f22f63318f1c8b814586ccf9952dcfe353d_lin; Path=/; Secure X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK X-ASESSIONID: 1amnj3o X-AUSERNAME: glgarcia Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 23:56:45 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 }}

Here's the Web API side:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateImagenesQuejasOpinionesSugerencia([FromForm] QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesRequest quejasImagenesRequest,string issueKey)
        {
            QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesResponse.Root quejasImagenesResponse = new QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesResponse.Root();
            //return System.Convert.ToBase64String(textAsBytes);
            try
            {

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Setting Base address.  
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://gestiondecasos.humano.local/");
   
                    // Initialization.  
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    // HTTP POST  
                    var imagenGuardo = quejasImagenesRequest.ConvertToBase64();
                    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/attachments", imagenGuardo).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Verification  
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Reading Response.  
                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        quejasImagenesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesResponse.Root>(result);
                    }
                }
                return Ok(quejasImagenesResponse);


            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share how you are sending the request from `postman`? In addition, can you include `QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesRequest` details?

Comment: What kind of request this method accepts `client.PostAsJsonAsync`, I mean the signature of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am making the call of that service through another api to be able to
> test it by Postman, it happens that when I do it and paste the image I
> get that 415 error. What could be happening?

Well, based on your `error message` couple of reason there might be of having that error, After my investigation I concluded into following findings:

**Content-Type: text/html:**

In your error message its clear that you have sent the content as `Content-Type: text/html;` however, your controller is expecting `[FromForm]`. From `postman` you should submit your request as following:

[image]

[image]

**Model:**

As you haven't shared your request `model details` therefore, I made the model as following to simulate the test.

```
public class QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesRequest
    {
       
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile files { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateImagenesQuejasOpinionesSugerencia([FromForm] QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesRequest quejasImagenesRequest, string issueKey)
        {
            string fileInBase64;
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    quejasImagenesRequest.files.CopyTo(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    fileInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                    // act on the Base64 data
                }

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Setting Base address.  
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:5094/");
                    // Initialization.  
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    // HTTP POST  
                   response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/rest/issue/{issueKey}/attachments", fileInBase64).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    // Verification  
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Reading Response.  
                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                       //quejasImagenesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuejasSugerenciaOpinionesImagenesResponse.Root>(result);
                    }
                }
                return Ok("");


            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

**API Test Controller:**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("issue/{issue}/attachments")]
        public IActionResult Rest([FromRoute]string issue, [FromBody]string attachments)
        {
            return Ok(attachments);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

I have simulate the test from `postman` using `from-date` format and send request to `API CreateImagenesQuejasOpinionesSugerencia` which is type of `[FromForm]` thus I have sent `one image file` and `one addtional parameter` as you can see the sreenshot, it hits the controller thereafter, convert it as `based64` and finally submit another request to `PostAsJsonAsync($"api/rest/issue/{issueKey}/attachments"` `API endpoint` which successfully reach the endpoint. If you still have any confusion please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you Md Farid, thats help me a lot!!

Comment: Glad to assist you on this.